# Unable to connect to minikube ingress via minikube ip

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

so I just got started digging into minikube after having problems with the docker-desktop here and there. I am following https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/, but I'm running into a problem.

I did exactly what the tutorial explains:

1. Enable the ingress addon in minikube (Does this work with self-deployed ingress controller installed via helm as well, by the way?)
2. Deployed an application
3. Created the corresponding Ingress configuration

I verified all is available, and end up with the following output of `kubectl get ingress`:

```
NAME              CLASS    HOSTS              ADDRESS        PORTS   AGE
example-ingress   <none>   hello-world.info   192.168.49.2   80      87m
```

However, when trying to access hello-world.info (either that, setup in my hosts file, or 192.168.49.2 directly, just for connectivity testing), I'm getting absolutely nothing besides request timeouts. The logs of my ingress-controller also don't mention any failed connection attempts.

The connection works just fine when manually starting a tunnel via `minikube service ingress-nginx-controller-admission --namespace=kube-system`.

Here's the output of `minikube profile list`:

```
|----------|-----------|---------|--------------|------|---------|---------|-------|
| Profile  | VM Driver | Runtime |      IP      | Port | Version | Status  | Nodes |
|----------|-----------|---------|--------------|------|---------|---------|-------|
| minikube | docker    | docker  | 192.168.49.2 | 8443 | v1.20.2 | Running |     1 |
|----------|-----------|---------|--------------|------|---------|---------|-------|
```

I'm running this example on a Windows machine via the docker-desktop runtime.

Where am I going wrong? My ultimate goal is to enable a docker-desktop like experience via my ingress. I don't want to have to manually enable / disable tunnels to access my cluster.

Comment: I am also having the same issue. And i do not understand what to do after running minikube tunnel How do you access the dummy domain. Do i map 127.0.0.1 hello-world.info in the windows hosts file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> (Does this work with self-deployed ingress controller installed via
> helm as well, by the way?)

- `minikube addons enable ingress` enables the minikube implementation of the [Nginx Ingress](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#minikube)

> My ultimate goal is to enable a docker-desktop
> like experience via my ingress. I don't want to have to manually
> enable / disable tunnels to access my cluster.

- Unfortunately, it is working as expected. After enabling ingress addon it is specifically stated that: `After the addon is enabled, please run "minikube tunnel" and your ingress resources would be available at "127.0.0.1"`. So in this scenario when using Minikube on Windows you are actually supposed to use [minikube tunnel](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/tunnel/). Bear in mind that Minikube is mainly used for testing and learning purposes so some of it's features might not be ideal.

Comment: Thanks - So there's no way to setup access to Minikube without manually forwarding something?

Comment: No, if you want to use/test `minikube addons enable ingress` with Windows you have to use `minikube tunnel`.

Comment: @nugetminer23 Does this [answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor. I am also having the same issue. And i do not understand what to do after running `minikube tunnel`  How do you access the dummy domain. Do i map `127.0.0.1 hello-world.info`  in the windows hosts file?

Comment: @Rakesh Please explain your exact use case in a separate question to avoid unnecessary mistakes and for better clarity.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor..I did not a new one because I am having exactly(And Que will be closed as duplicate) the same issue as the OP. I have the same output OP has posted for `kubectl get ingress` And I am also trying to access `hello-world.info` via browser or curl

Comment: Que in Stackoverflow : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66206451/kubernetes-ingress-flask-application

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get Ingress working on minikube (Windows 10, Docker Desktop) after two weeks of trying. `minikube tunnel` gives me access to `127.0.0.1/80` but I could never reach out to the ingress routes. Have you tried [kind](https://techdozo.dev/2021/getting-started-with-kind-quick-start-a-multi-node-local-kubernetes-cluster/)? Even though setting up Ingress is quite involved in `kind` but it works. I have written an article [Getting started with Kind](https://techdozo.dev/2021/getting-started-with-kind-quick-start-a-multi-node-local-kubernetes-cluster/).

Comment: Yes! I have switched to kind a few months ago, and I'm very happy with it. I works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

My case I missed to enable ingress. Below command can use to enable ingress

```
minikube addons enable ingress
```

Before enable ingress addons

```
kubectl get ingress
```

| NAME | CLASS | HOSTS | ADDRESS | PORTS | AGE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| app |  | app.com |  | 80 | 23m |

After enabled ingress addons

```
kubectl get ingress
```

| NAME | CLASS | HOSTS | ADDRESS | PORTS | AGE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| app |  | app.com | 172.20.114.70 | 80 | 23m |